# Watson Developer java-sdk STT

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, watson, language-translation

Getting this error in sample app.

> java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '401
>   Not Authorized'

Using this code snippet to transalate.

```
TranslateOptions translateOptions = new TranslateOptions.Builder()
                             .addText(params[0])
                             .source(Language.ENGLISH)
                             .target(selectedTargetLanguage)
                             .build();

TranslationResult translationResult = translationService
                             .translate(translateOptions)
                             .execute();
```

Once it executes the application crashes and I see this error in logs.

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2/translate/v2/translate http/1.1 (46-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Not Authorized https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2/translate/v2/translate (413ms, unknown-length body)

POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2/translate/v2/translate, status: 401, error: Not Authorized

--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: com.gobiggi.watsontutorial, PID: 10136

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Caused by:

com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Tip: Did you set the Endpoint?

at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:410)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:174)
at com.gobiggi.watsontutorial.MainActivity$TranslationTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:328)
at com.gobiggi.watsontutorial.MainActivity$TranslationTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:321)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Well... are you authorized to use the service? As far as I know you need to pay for Watson. Do you have an account? Did you send your username / password from inside Java at all?

Comment: Yes I did. It’s working when I do it in postman.

Comment: You have `/api/v2/translate/v2/translate`. Looks like duplication of the url construction.

Comment: I cannot see in your source code where you are setting username or password: Builder -> addText -> source -> target -> build, and execute. Nothing about passwords.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know too much about how watson sdk works but just by looking at the error i see:

> com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException:
>   Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Tip: Did
>   you set the Endpoint?

Is saying the credentials presented are not valid. You should start by looking at that.

Comment: Maybe there is an authentication header or some header missing on your request. check the postman request and compare it with the one you are sending. Can u post more of the code you're using? You are setting username and password as doc says in the form:
LanguageTranslator service = new LanguageTranslator();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");